# Chromedriver option is missing for this command "npm init wdio ."

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, webdriver-io, geckodriver

Whenever I type a command for package installation for [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/), I am not seeing the **chromedriver** or **geckodriver** option.

Instead I am getting the options below

```
Do you want to add a service to your test setup? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection, 
and <enter> to proceed)
❯◯ vite
 ◯ nuxt
 ◯ firefox-profile
 ◯ gmail
 ◯ sauce
 ◯ testingbot
 ◯ crossbrowsertesting
```

Answer (score 0):

> With WebdriverIO v8.14 and above there is no need to manually download and setup any browser drivers anymore as this is handled by WebdriverIO. All you have to do is specify the browser you want to test and WebdriverIO will do the rest.

More info here - https://webdriver.io/docs/driverbinaries/